# Silex Microframework for Dreamhost shared hosting

Tags: php, dreamhost

i can enable phar extension but i get this error:

> Warning: Unexpected character in input: '\' (ASCII=92) state=1 in /home/cesartineo/tineo.mobi/public/silex/silex.phar on line 27
>
> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in
>   /home/cesartineo/tineo.mobi/public/silex/silex.phar on line 27

i use the example .htaccess and index.php from the silex web.

```
require_once __DIR__.'/silex.phar';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function ($name) use ($app) {
    return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're running on PHP 5.3.2 or later.

Good luck!

Comment: Could you provide a little more detail about why this would solve tineo's issue?

Comment: yes, i'm using PHP 5.3 (FastCGI) and i followed the steps from http://serverfault.com/a/317573/97460

Comment: Dear Royce Williams, Because I faced same problem and when I change my PHP version to 5.3.2 it's working fine! Using PHP 5.3.2 is mandatory to working fine!